# PHP - Зачитать из файла "n" строк, начиная от "x" строки, заканчивая "y" строкой

Tags: php

Есть файл с n-м количеством строк. Нужно при помощи PHP зачитать строки, например, от 40-й до 80-й.

Нашёл в сети похожее решение, но оно работает так: я указываю сколько строк от начала надо пропустить, а все остальные зачитываются...это немного не то...может кто поможет модифицировать код, что бы можно было указать начальную и конечную строки ? 
Вот сам код:

```
<?php

final class FileReader
{
protected $handler = null;
protected $fbuffer = "";


/**
 * Конструктор класса, открывающий файл для работы
 *
 * @param string $filename
 */
public function __construct($filename)
{
    if(!($this->handler = fopen($filename, "rb")))
        throw new Exception("Cannot open the file");
}


/**
 * Построчное чтение всего файла с учетом сдвига
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function ReadAll()
{
    if(!$this->handler)
        throw new Exception("Invalid file pointer");

    while(!feof($this->handler))
        $this->fbuffer .= fgets($this->handler);

    return $this->fbuffer;
}


/**
 * Установить строку, с которой производить чтение файла
 *
 * @param int  $line
 */
public function SetOffset($line)
{
    if(!$this->handler)
        throw new Exception("Invalid file pointer");

    while(!feof($this->handler) && $line--) {
        fgets($this->handler);
    }
}
};

/**
 * Пример использования 
 */
$stream = new FileReader("lines.txt");

// Укажем, что читать надо с 20-ой строки
$stream->SetOffset(20);

// Получаем содержимое
echo $stream->ReadAll();

/**
* Количество прочитанных строк можно узнать так:
*
* echo count(explode("\n", $stream->ReadAll()));
*/


?>
```

Буду очень благодарен за помощь!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перепишите readAll так

```
public function ReadLines($start, $stop)
{
    $count = $stop-$start+1;
    $start = $start - 1;
    while(!feof($this->handler) && $start--) {
        fgets($this->handler);
    }
    if(!$this->handler)
        throw new Exception("Invalid file pointer");

    $this->fbuffer = "";
    while(!feof($this->handler) && $count--) {
        $this->fbuffer .= fgets($this->handler);
    }

    return $this->fbuffer;
}
```

и вызывайте так

```
echo $stream->ReadLines(20,40);
```

читает с 20 до 40 включительно.

код писался прямо тут, так что лучше проверяйте на ошибки.

Comment: Да конструктивное замечание

Comment: А почему хандлер проверяется после использования?

Comment: @Naumov зачем там вообще проверять его если в конструкторе это уже сделано?